# Should I Upgrade Or Fresh Installation?

Tags: upgrade, 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is a clean install better than upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5466/is-a-clean-install-better-than-upgrading)

Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric Ocelot) will be out soon. Should I upgrade it using Update Manager or using fresh installation? Which one is better? What the pros & cons upgrading using Update Manager?

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you are talking about *after* 11.10 (Oneiric) has been released - [as per this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do), it's pretty buggy.

This is highly subjective, but I always do a fresh install, for a number of reasons:

- Ubuntu gets somewhat bogged down after 6 months.
- A fresh install (as opposed to a upgrade) keeps possible dependency conflicts to a minimum.
- I like playing with new shiny features without having old configs/packages around to screw up.

How do I do it?

1. Download release via torrent, seed for a few days (I'm running Ubuntu+1 by then anyway)
2. Once I notice that demand has dropped off, I create a new folder on
   my `/home` partition and call it something like `Stuff I need to
   keep`.
3. I create my bootable USB key.
4. I install.
5. After that, I boot into my new install, and start transferring data
   from that directory I made earlier.
6. Done!