# Is it better do upgrade system from existing Ubuntu installation, or to install a fresh version?

Tags: system-installation

So far every time I have uninstalled a new version of Ubuntu I have done a clean install of the system, and after that I have installed all programs all over again, but now I am thinking as I have a quite many programs installed currently on my Ubuntu version:

Is it "`safe`" to update my version of Ubuntu to the latest 13.10 or it is the best to use the '`old school`' way and to install a `fresh` installation and then try to install and transfer all data and programs that I had in previous version? `What is better option`?

Comment: The short answer is you should always have backup.

Comment: :))) and I intending to :))

Comment: I was more thinking whether my newly `upgraded` version will be buggy even if I manage to upgrade safely..

Comment: This is a lot like asking which is the one true religion - lots of strong opinion on each side. Personally, I've done both, both have worked well, but that backup . . . . yeah.

Comment: see also http://askubuntu.com/questions/60803/should-i-upgrade-or-fresh-installation