# i am planning to upgrade my ubuntu 11.04 to 12.04 but confused...should i upgrade or perform a fresh install?

Tags: installation, upgrade, software-center

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is a clean install better than upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5466/is-a-clean-install-better-than-upgrading)

i want to perform a fresh installation with all my installed softwares and my documents safe...can i use APTonCD to recover installed programs and my documents....can APTonCD do that for me...
i don't want to upgrade because my internet connection is slow...and my internet plan does not allow me to download a large amount of data in a day....it would take me many days to upgrade...
tell me what should i do 
also tell me about use of the software APTonCD which i downloaded from ubuntu software center...