# Updating QT to 5.9 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, package-management, pdf, qt

For the purpose of installing Master PDF Editor, which I would use to troubleshoot a separate problem, I need a more up-to-date version of QT. When I run `sudo dpkg -i master-pdf-editor-4.2.70_qt5.amd64.deb` I get the following error:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of master-pdf-editor:
 master-pdf-editor depends on libqt5svg5 (>= 5.4); however:
  Version of libqt5svg5:amd64 on system is 5.2.1-1.
 master-pdf-editor depends on libqt5network5 (>= 5.4); however:
  Version of libqt5network5:amd64 on system is 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3.
 master-pdf-editor depends on libqt5gui5 (>= 5.4); however:
  Version of libqt5gui5:amd64 on system is 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3.
 master-pdf-editor depends on libqt5printsupport5 (>= 5.4); however:
  Version of libqt5printsupport5:amd64 on system is 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.3.
```

I have tried following [these instruction](http://wiki.qt.io/Install_Qt_5_on_Ubuntu) (for QT 5.9) but at the following step:

> Edit a file named “defaults.list” in the same directory. Add the
>   following line.
>
> `text/qtcreator=Qt-Creator.desktop;`

I have the problem that no file `defaults.list` exists in `/.local/share/applications`. Proceeding without completing this step doesn't seem to update the various `libqt5` packages that need updating. What should I do to meet the `Master PDF Editor` dependencies?

Comment: You looking the wrong dir, it says `~/.local/share/applications`. That said, I still don't see a step that could've placed the file in there, so might need to create it. Why the hassle though, 14.04 is ancient, perhaps it's better to just upgrade the system?

Comment: @Hi-Angel Sorry, I meant to write `/.local/share/applications`. I would be happy to upgrade my system but I worry that it may break something. Namely, I don't want my OpenAI Gym to break, nor my DropBox folder. Is upgrading generally safe? I know 16.04 includes the versions of QT I need so presumably upgrading to 16.04 is a solution.

Comment: Uh, well, it's a hard question, especially given I am on Archlinux. I'd say, there's no guarantee. **UPD**: may be [this answer would be more helpful](https://askubuntu.com/a/5471/266507).