# Upgrade from non-LTS to LTS or install a fresh LTS?

Tags: upgrade, 17.10, 18.04

At the moment I have 17.10 installed. Now I wonder which is safer, more stable and clean:

- To upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04
- Install a fresh 18.04

If they are the same, I prefer to do the upgrade as it saves me some time. In another word, does fresh LTS install has any advantages over upgrade from non-LTS?

Comment: I would go for a fresh install which will ensure any drivers are also covered. Moreover, I would be inclined to wait until the next point release is available (suggested by July/August).

Comment: My suggestion: backup, upgrade, see if you like how everything performs, if things seem more sluggish than usual do a fresh install

Comment: It is a matter of opinion. Some like to upgrade, while others prefer to reinstall. Both are not 100% safe stable and clean, whatever that even means, but both had been tested, and are known to work reasonably well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is a clean install better than upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5466/is-a-clean-install-better-than-upgrading)

Comment: I did upgrade and everything seems normal but as there might be some configurations that upgrade process is not able to change, I'm considering fress installation of LTS. My previous fresh install was 17.10, if it was a LTS I was OK BTW.