# Ubuntu 16.04 won't boot: stuck on black screen with dev/sda1: clean, ../.. files, ../.. blocks

Tags: 16.04

my laptop (Thinkpad t450, Ubuntu 16.04) won't boot anymore, it stays stuck on

```
/dev/sda1: clean,  nnn/nnn files, nnn/nnn blocks
```

I have tried to `$ sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` and fsck at boot, but it doesn't help.

I managed to boot in the previous kernel though.
The new kernel that won't boot is: `Linux 4.4.0-174-generic`...

Can you help please ?

Thanks

Edit: `$ dpkg -l | awk '!/^rc/ && / linux-(c|g|h|i|lo|m|si|t)/{print $1,$2,$3,$4 | "sort -k3 | column -t"}'` gives :

```
ii  linux-headers-4.4.0-173                 4.4.0-173.203  all
ii  linux-headers-4.4.0-173-generic         4.4.0-173.203  amd64
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-173-generic           4.4.0-173.203  amd64
ii  linux-modules-4.4.0-173-generic         4.4.0-173.203  amd64
ii  linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-173-generic   4.4.0-173.203  amd64
ii  linux-image-unsigned-4.4.0-174-generic  4.4.0-174.204  amd64
ii  linux-modules-4.4.0-174-generic         4.4.0-174.204  amd64
```

Edit: `$ lspci -v | grep "VGA controller"` 
gives

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

and `$ glxinfo|egrep "OpenGL vendor|OpenGL renderer*"`
gives:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2)
```

[image]

Comment: Different laptop bit this happened to me a few days ago after upgrade kernel, and the culprit was indeed Nvidia. If you have CUDA installed, uninstall them. Also, can you include your grub setting ? flags you included in your grub ?

Comment: Please do not just purge NVIDIA and reboot, Run `sudo apt purge nvidia-*` then run `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` then reboot from the recovery mode. Please refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1163539/968501) for help.

Comment: Please remember providing feedback (voting + accepting + commenting, according to your experience), for the benefit of the community.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that this is a problem with the 16.04 LTS Hardware support.
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus) was released in 2016 and support is officially given until April 2021. However on this older LTS kernels there are only safety relevant upgrades and minimum maintainence done. Also HW support for newer HW is limited.
May I know why you not update to newer version of Ubuntu?
Currently you would be able to go to 18.04 (Bionic Beaver) or you stay on the previous kernel version .173 you used a bit longer and change to with
brand new 20.04 (Focal Fossa) after release:

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/timeline/38cea234e4bed0ccfff76511d6f72782.png

My proposal:

a) stay on 4.4.xx.173 and leave it for now. (changes in .174 are minor)

b) consider a Distribution upgrade 
download a newer Ubuntu version (f.e. 18.04 LTS) , create a USB Starter and try it.
If everything works and you like it, then upgrade your system.
MAKE SURE YOU BACKUP ALL BEFORE
Also 2 options:
- Direct install from Pendrive
  + you get a clean new system with all the newest X Environments and settings
  - You will loose many former settings but your Home directory Data should be preserved

- Upgrade inside your running system with

apt-get dist-upgrade 
or the Ubuntu way
sudo do-release-upgrade

That way many of your settings and Windowmanager aso is preserved...but sometimes it creates conflicts

Hope that helps you

Comment: ok thanks a lot for your answer. I am considering the upgrade to 18.04 LTS, I think you're right. I was afraid that upgrade over a non-working version of ubuntu was not a good idea...

Comment: Please mark this as the accepted answer if it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

I have seen other issues related to disconnects between kernel version and supported hardware.

Given that you have 16.04LTS, I guess it can be a good time for an upgrade.
As per the [Ubuntu release cycle](https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle) below, I suggest you work with kernel ...173 and wait until mid/end April for 20.04LTS (cross fingers, covid-19 was in nobody's plans).

Notes:

1. You would be facing the dilemma upgrade vs. clean install...

[Is a clean install better than upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5466/is-a-clean-install-better-than-upgrading)

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2390257

2. Please take all precautions related to a system upgrade. Essentially, backing up suitably.

[image]