# Differences between fresh install and the result of do-release-upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I'm thinking about upgrading my Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04.
Will be any difference between the upgraded systems if I do a fresh install and configure it to the current setup and the result of do-release-upgrade? (except the lost log files)

Comment: Actually not, because I'd like to know the differences between the fresh install and the upgraded system. For example, the upgraded system will contain many unnecessary files, config files which aren't working with the new system etc. I know, that a fresh install is cleaner, sometimes simpler but I have many, manually edited config files etc.

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1035324/) which has been tested on a 18.04 to 20.04 upgrade and updated to Ubuntu 20.04 contains information about what to do when the upgraded system contains unnecessary files, config files which aren't working with the new system, etc.